# Securing Spring (4.2.8.RELEASE) Http Remote methods is causing Error creating bean / No matching factory method found: factory bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Example is now in: https://github.com/theodorebmiller/springSecurityRemoteIssue

I am attempting to secure a method published using HttpInvokerServiceExporter.  When I add @Secured to the method in class being published, I get Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

The application already has Spring Security (4.2.8.RELEASE). working at the method level.  I have tested that it works with @Secured commented, but fails when @Secured is present.

I have tried it on more than service, with the same outcomes.

Placing @Secured on a method that is not being exported, everything is just fine.

I have googled the heck out of this, but cannot seem to find anything.

Here is how I have coded it, and the stack trace I am getting.

> @Component(value = "docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade") 
>     @Conditional(RemoteBeanPublishingValidator.class)
>     public class DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl 
>                   extends DocSaveServiceRemoteBase {
>
> . . .
>
> @Bean(name = "/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade")
>     public HttpInvokerServiceExporter DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade() {
>         HttpInvokerServiceExporter exporter = 
>                new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
>         exporter.setService(this);
>         exporter.setServiceInterface(DocSaveService.class);
>         return exporter;    } 
>      ...
>
> @Override  @Secured("InternetUsers")
>      public ExpressDocumentBase saveExpressDocument(ExpressDocumentBase doc,
>                                InputStream source) {
>         return docSaveService.saveExpressDocument(doc, source);
>      }

I expected it to work just as it does on non-exported methods.

What I am getting is this:

2019-09-12 11:20:07,550 WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ==> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
2019-09-12 11:20:07,551 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader ==> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

2019-09-12 11:20:07,557 ERROR org.jboss.msc.service.fail ==> MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."DocSaveExampleEar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.ear"."DocSaveExampleWar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."DocSaveExampleEar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.ear"."DocSaveExampleWar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more

2019-09-12 11:20:07,564 ERROR org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation ==> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "DocSaveExampleEar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DocSaveExampleEar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"DocSaveExampleWar-tbm_work-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/DocSaveServiceHttpFacade' defined in class path resource [com/ttiinc/docSaveExample/web/remoteService/docSave/DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteImpl.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'docSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade'; factory method 'DocSaveServiceHttpRemoteFacade()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static."}}

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look at this. Is this something that you could simplify into a minimal sample on GitHub? Send me the GitHub link and I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it took a bit to cut it out of the original application.  It can be found at https://github.com/theodorebmiller/springSecurityRemoteIssue

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look